# Philippines passport holder transit visa

Tags: transit, luggage, nrt

I bought my e-ticket through an online travel agency PAL- Air Canada. From Manila, layover 3h and 55 mins in Narita Tokyo terminal 2. I will transfer terminals and airlines from terminal 2 to terminal 1 and depart with Air Canada. Do I need to claim my check in luggage in Narita or it will be checked in through to my last destination?

Comment: Title and question (the thing with a question mark) don't match

Answer (score 1):

Unless your transit is an overnight layover, you do not need a transit visa for Tokyo.

From [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=VI&COUNTRY=jp&SUBSECTION=TW&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX):

> Visa required, except for holders of onward tickets transiting on the same calendar day.

Narita's transit area closes overnight, so you will have to enter Japan if your departing flight is the next calendar day - however, you should be eligible for a `Shore Pass` in this instance:

> Holders of onward tickets transiting to a third country can obtain a Shore Pass on arrival for a max. stay of 72 hours only if there are no connecting flights on the same calendar day